# Where to download kernel rpm directly?

Tags: kernel, rpm

Here provides some new (5.x) kernel rpm:

`https://elrepo.org/linux/kernel/el7/x86_64/RPMS/`

Is any place that still provide 4.x kernel rpm?

#Edit:

I am looking for CentOS/Redhat update.

Comment: That’s usually distro specific- which distro are you trying to get a kernel for?

Comment: I think el7 is for CentOS7/Redhat7.

Comment: True, but kernel 5.x is not mainline for any el7 distro that I’m aware of. Just disabling elrepo should be enough to use yum download...

Comment: El7 doesn’t have official 4.x kernels. You could try the elrepo archive https://mirror.imt-systems.com/elrepo/archive/kernel/el7/x86_64/RPMS/

Comment: Use yum’s showduplicates flag to see any available

Answer (score 1):

RPMs are distribution dependent. So, for example, you might get older RPMs for Fedora from https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases. Not all kernel releases will be available that way though.

If you need a specific kernel, it may require some search in the archives of the different RPM-distributions.

Otherwise, the official tarbal from kernel.org could be an option.